# How to unhide hidden objects?

Tags: modifiers

so I hid some masked object with Hide (box) shortcut H, and now I want to unhide hidden objects so I can work with them again. Can't seem to find how.

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
It also selects everything that was hidden. Works with hidden parts of your mesh in Edit Mode and Hidden Objects in Object Mode.